# W3 total cache caches pages for HTTPS 'uniquely' what does that mean?

Tags: wordpress, ssl, caching, w3-total-cache

W3 total cache reads:

Cache SSL (https) requests
Cache SSL requests (uniquely) for improved performance.

[image]

now i want hard caching for all pages, if https or not, that always a cached version is returned. Thing is, i cannot disable https for the pages, as we would be ranking lower on google, as non https gives you a penalty nowadays.

what does this sentence really mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short version: this means that the page caching rules will not cache HTTPS specific pages by default.  So (http : // example . com / page1) would be cached but (https :// example.com / page2) would not be.
Making this `true` then cause the cache to automatically create a specific SSL version of the page cache.

By default the option is [set to false](https://github.com/crowdfavorite-mirrors/wp-w3-total-cache/blob/f14fa4fe8c908109c44939d5e27360fe7ae7b01d/ConfigKeys.php):

```
'pgcache.cache.ssl' => array(
        'type' => 'boolean',
        'default' => false
```

If set to true then:

```
/**
         * Set HTTPS
         */
        if ( $config->get_boolean( 'pgcache.cache.ssl' ) ) {
            $rules .= "    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on\n";
            $rules .= "    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_SSL:_ssl]\n";
            $rules .= "    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443\n";
            $rules .= "    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_SSL:_ssl]\n";
            $env_W3TC_SSL = '%{ENV:W3TC_SSL}';
        }
```

Comment: so uniquely PER USER? uniquely what? uniquely for all SSL request? and default seemed to be true, that is, default this option was clicked

Comment: "Uniquely" meaning that you will have up to two versions of the page cached - a non-secure version and a secure version.  There's no per-user element because the w3 total cache is typically only for not-logged-in-users.